# Modify the audio content of CMSampleBuffer without creating copy of it and write the file

Tags: swift, xcode, buffer, cmsamplebuffer

I am capturing the audio content which is stored in CMSampleBuffer. Now I want to access the audio samples directly from the buffer without creating copy of it and perform some modifications on it (say silence the audio / apply pitch effect) and write the modified sample buffer into the file. Can anyone help me to achieve this in Swift